# Creating a capped collection with mongoose & mongodb not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a capped collection in mongoose (@2.7.1, mongo v2.0.6) via node.js.

I've [copied the basic code from the mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#capped) to create a test case:

```
    var schema = new Schema({'test':String},{capped:1024});
    var model = api.db.model('testcapped',schema);
    var data = new model({'test': 'value'});
    data.save();
```

This executes without errors.
However, when I subsequently use a mongo shell...

```
> db.testcappeds.isCapped();
false
```

On the other hand, if I do this in node.js, it works:

```
model.db.db.executeDbCommand({'convertToCapped': 'testcappeds', size: 1024}, function(e,d){});
```

In other words, bypassing mongoose directly calling the "convertToCapped" command is successfully working, but mongoose is not correctly capping the collection.

Am I missing something? Should I just manually cap the collection with the working code, or will this add performance overhead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[These](http://www.slideshare.net/aaronheckmann/mongoose-v3-the-future-is-bright) slides indicate that Mongoose 2.7.1 does not yet support capped collections.  I would recommend either dropping down into the native driver to make the collection capped, or upgrade to the newest Mongoose.